# Where I can read about Dart language feature that called "internal libraries"?

Tags: dart

This my code produces error: `The library 'dart:_collection-dev' is internal and cannot be imported`.

```dart
import 'dart:_collection-dev';
```

Although this code works:

```dart
library dart.collection;

import 'dart:_collection-dev';
```

I take this message literally, as it is, and I have a question.

How this possible in Dart language 1.1 having internal libraries?

Accordingly to [The Dart Programming Language Specification (1.1)](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html) there is no such thing as internal libraries that cannot be imported outside of package.

Where I can read about this undocumented language feature that called "internal libraries" and how I can write internal libraries in Dart language?

P.S.

Is this means that Dart SDK written not in Dart language?

Dart joins ECMA [TC52 - Dart](http://www.ecma-international.org/memento/TC52.htm).

Will this non-Dart language features be standardized in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internal libraries are VM/dart2js internal features. Given that normal users cannot access them there is no need to standardize them in TC52.

Yes: the Dart SDK uses features that are not part of the Dart language specification. Some of them are necessary to avoid code-duplication between the VM and dart2js (see your question about patch-files), others are used to hide code that the Dart library developers are not willing to support publicly.